# Converting class instance with private variables into JSON format

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, client

I have the following code for a class. I want to convert this into a JSON so that I can send it to an API. After converting to JSON, I am getting:

```
{"_Test__id": 3}
```

I want id only in place of `"_Test__id"`. Is there any way to do it without making id public in this class.

```
from json import JSONEncoder

class Test:

    def __init__(self, id=0):
        self.__id = id

    def _get_id(self):
        return self.__id

    def _set_id(self, value):
        self.__id = value

    id= property(_get_id, _set_id)


class TestEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__

obj = Test(3)
print(TestEncoder().encode(obj))
```

Comment: If it's not public, why does it need to be in the JSON encoding? That said, you should construct the exact `dict` object you want `default` to return, rather than relying on `__dict__`.

Comment: Your `property` is totally pointless. Note, **python doesn't have private variables**, everything is public. What you have here is a pointless property named `id`, but `property` belongs to the *class* (as it should). You should probably just define your own `to_dict` method, and then your `TestEncoder` should try to call `to_dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be explicit.

```
def default(self, o):
    return {'id': self.__id}
```

Comment: What if there are 10 private fields?

Comment: Then you list them explicitly.

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'TestEncoder' object has no attribute '_TestEncoder__id' error

Comment: Also, there are many classes with private attributes which I need in JSON format.

Comment: @oxy_js: Use a single, not double, underscore prefixes. The latter causes name-mangling to occur.

Comment: @oxy_js *this is supposed to be defined in class of which you are trying to encode, not in `TestEncoder`*

Comment: @oxy_js I highly suspect you are incorrectly using `property` when you should have simple attributes. If these properties you are defininig follow the same pattern as your `Test` class, you shouldn't be using them that way

Comment: When should we use private variables then?

Comment: @oxy_js **there are no private variables in Python**. This is *very important to understand*. You can never use them, because they don't exist. Again, I highly suspect you are trying to bring concepts from languages like Java/C++ which do not apply to Python.

Comment: I just started from JAVA. Thanks for your help.